# How can I "adapt" a Task<IEnumerable<T>> to IAsyncEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, system.interactive

I'm incrementally introducing Ix.NET into a legacy project.  I have a number of storage-level APIs that return `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`, but I want to adapt them to `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` for consumption in the rest of the system.  It seems like there should be a helper method (ala `.ToAsyncEnumerable()` for IEnumerable) to help with this, but I can't find anything...  Do I have to implement my own custom Enumerator?  (not hard, but I don't want to re-invent the wheel)

Comment: Why are you preferring `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` over `IObservable<T>`?

Comment: Server-side, I want to stick with `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` for alignment with C# 8.0 async streams (which I want to eventually adopt for this scenario).  On the client, I will be wrapping the response stream produced by this enumerable in an observable.

Answer (score 8):

```
Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetSomeResults<T>()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

async IAsyncEnumerable<T> GetAsyncEnumerable<T>()
{
    var results = await GetSomeResults<T>();
    foreach(var item in results)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As commented by [Theodor Zoulias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55384089/how-can-i-adapt-a-taskienumerablet-to-iasyncenumerablet#comment120200874_68002385),
[System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) is a NuGet package from [.NET Foundation](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/dotnetfoundation), which supports `ToAsyncEnumerable()`.

Example usage:

```
    var tasks = new Task[0]; // get your IEnumerable<Task>s
    tasks.ToAsyncEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about web APIs, `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` is an asynchronous way of producing a `IEnumerable<T>`.

Regardless of that `IEnumerable<T>` being produced synchronously or asynchronously, the whole list will be sent as an HTTP response.

The way you could leverage `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` on the client is if that client is invoking some kind of streaming or making multiple requests to a server for a unique list of results (paging).

Comment: Yes, exactly! :-)  For server-side, I want to enable asynchronous consumption of the Enumerable, and on the client, I want to move to using streaming responses.

Comment: How do you expect to do that.

Comment: On the server, I can naturally process the IAsyncEnumerable using the Linq extension methods in System.Interactive.Async, and for the client, I will construct an observable over a response that uses chunked transfer encoding (ala https://medium.com/@deaniusaur/how-to-stream-json-data-over-rest-with-observables-80e0571821d3).

Comment: I'm surely missing something here. An `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` is used for asynchronously pull data from a source. I don't see an immediate advantage of doing that on a WebAPI. What's pushed to the client is an `IEnumerable<T>`. Maybe if you could show some code...

Comment: So, what I want to achieve on the client side is asynchronously streaming entities (of type T) over an open GET request as I fetch them (again, asynchronously) from the data source on the server.  That said, this is all getting away from the original question. 

Putting the client piece aside, just looking at the server piece, I want to be able to create an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` from a `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`, and I'm just looking for the most elegant way to do that (without writing my own Enumerator).

Comment: That is, I have the following interface I need to implement: `interface IDataSource<T> { IAsyncEnumerable<T> GetData(); }` ...and the client I'm using to fetch the data has the following signature: `class OldDatabaseClient<T> { Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetData() }` What's the simplest (relatively efficient) way to implement the interface?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the exact same thing, and due to the replies here I assume that there is indeed no method like `AsAsyncEnumerable()`. So here's what I ended up doing, maybe it helps someone else:

```
public static class AsyncEnumerableExtensions {
    public struct AsyncEnumerable<T> : IAsyncEnumerable<T> {
        private readonly IEnumerable<T> enumerable;

        public AsyncEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) {
            this.enumerable = enumerable;
        }

        public IAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken()) {
            return new AsyncEnumerator<T>(enumerable?.GetEnumerator());
        }
    }

    public struct AsyncEnumerator<T> : IAsyncEnumerator<T> {
        private readonly IEnumerator<T> enumerator;

        public AsyncEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> enumerator) {
            this.enumerator = enumerator;
        }

        public ValueTask DisposeAsync() {
            enumerator?.Dispose();
            return default;
        }

        public ValueTask<bool> MoveNextAsync() {
            return new ValueTask<bool>(enumerator == null ? false : enumerator.MoveNext());
        }

        public T Current => enumerator.Current;
    }

    public static AsyncEnumerable<T> AsAsyncEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> that) {
        return new AsyncEnumerable<T>(that);
    }

    public static AsyncEnumerator<T> AsAsyncEnumerator<T>(this IEnumerator<T> that) {
        return new AsyncEnumerator<T>(that);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually a method like the `AsAsyncEnumerable` already exists in the [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) package (owned by the [dotnetfoundation](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/dotnetfoundation)), and it's named [`ToAsyncEnumerable`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/ToAsyncEnumerable.cs).

Answer (score 1):

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> ToAsyncEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    using IEnumerator<T> enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();

    while (await Task.Run(enumerator.MoveNext).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        yield return enumerator.Current;
    }
}
```